# picture taken in expo uploading to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, camera, expo

The picture is being taken and saving to the gallery but it's not uploading to my firebase account. What am I doing wrong here?

Firebase is configed and connected in my app (i'm using it to authenticate and login to the app).

````
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true, skipProcessing: true };
      const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
      //camera roll (saving picture)
      const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(data.uri);
    
      const source = data.uri;
      console.log(data);
      if (source) {
        await cameraRef.current.pausePreview();
        setIsPreview(true);
        console.log("picture source", source);
      }

// uploading it to firebase
      const response = await fetch(data.uri);
      uploadImage = async (uri) => {
        const blob = await response.blob();
        var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("my-image");
        return ref.put(blob);
      }
    }

 

  };```
````